# Going on a holiday vs going on holiday?

Tags: grammar

I’ve been trying to find an answer to this and it seems that “going on holiday” is a standard phrase for British English. I’m not a native English speaker and “going for a holiday” seems much more natural for me.

Is it wrong? Why is the article omitted?

Comment: One is using it as a mass noun (a generic activity), the other as something specific (referencing a particular trip). If I'm off work, I could say that I'm *on holiday*. But if I'm actually travelling somewhere, I could say that I'm *on **a** holiday*. (Although I'd tend to use *vacation* rather than *holiday* in both cases.) Either is fine. You may be right that the article is dropped more often in the UK, but I'm not sure. I've heard it used both ways. (Then again, I'm in Canada.)

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. We need additional context to provide an accurate answer, as there are multiple things *go on holiday* and *go on a holiday* can mean, in both British and American Englishes. *Going for a holiday* similarly can mean the same thing as *going on a holiday*, but can also mean something different. Please [edit] your post to describe the situation.

Comment: If you're in the US you're going *on a holiday* (or going on vacation).  If you're in the UK you just go *on holiday*.